# Email evading my spam filter

Tags: centos, iptables, firewall, exim

I'm having trouble with email evading my Barracuda Spam firewall. I believe the spammers are using my A Record to bypass my MX Record which is what directs email to my Barracuda for processing.

How can I block (all) email from all sources other than my Barracuda?

I'm running Centos 6, whm, cpanel and exim.

Thanks!

Comment: I'd guess the easiest way to be iptables. Only allow smtp from your Barracuda, localhost, and possibly your LAN.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming Barracuda have correct rDNS records, add an ACL at helo time and only accept connections which verify and are from their domain.  The following should be a good starting point.  The Exim documentation provides additional details.

These rules could be added at connect time, but is likely to result in legitimate servers retrying.  However, they could be used in a mail or recipient acl.

```
acl_local_helo:

   # Accept connections received over a local interface, and from hosts
   # for which we relay mail.
  accept
    hosts = : +relay_from_hosts


  # Verify reverse DNS lookup of the sender's host.
  # Disable piplining and delay on failure.
  accept
    verify = reverse_host_lookup
    hosts = *.baracuda.xxx

  # Deny all others
  # start with defer until you are sure the rules are working 
  defer
```